# Multiple Left Join and SUM Not adding correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sum

Hey all I am trying to get SUM to work with a LEFT join query and it simply will not add the values up, even though when I return the results in a WHILE statement it shows the correct values to be added.

```
$lpcntWbqa = "SELECT portfolio_ledger.*,SUM(portfolio_ledger.plAmount) AS sum, portfolio_info.*,properties.*,property_portfolio.* 
FROM portfolio_ledger 
LEFT JOIN portfolio_info ON portfolio_ledger.psID = portfolio_info.ID 
LEFT JOIN property_portfolio ON portfolio_info.ppID = property_portfolio.ppID 
LEFT JOIN properties ON property_portfolio.pID = properties.pID 
WHERE properties.pOwner = '".$oRow['oID']."' 
AND portfolio_ledger.plNotify >= DATE_FORMAT( CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y/%m/01' ) 
AND portfolio_ledger.plNotify < DATE_FORMAT( CURRENT_DATE, '%Y/%m/01' ) 
AND (portfolio_ledger.plName = 'ST-Booking Fee' 
OR portfolio_ledger.plName = 'LT-Booking Fee') 
GROUP BY portfolio_ledger.psID";
```

While testing I am returning the results as such.

```
// testing
 while ($alpTypeRow = mysql_fetch_array($lpcntXbqa))
 {
    echo "Booking: ".$alpTypeRow['plID']." - ".$alpTypeRow['plAmount']."<br />";
    $lastMonthsBookingValue = number_format($alpTypeRow['sum'], 2, '.', '');
 }
 echo $lastMonthsBookingValue;
// end testing
```

The echo back results in 2 rows for the particular date range, which is correct:  1250 and 850 for the values, however the $lastMonthsBookingValue is only returning 850.  Not the items added together.

Any advice or assistance would be appreciated.  I have been researching on the net and maybe I need to do a nested SELECT but am unsure as to how to do this.

Comment: Are you expecting some NULL columns? Is that why you do the LEFT JOIN? Try moving `properties.pOwner = '".$oRow['oID']."' ` to the `JOIN` clause rather than the `WHERE`

Comment: I finally got this working. It seemed to be the GROUP BY aspect, and some irregular data in my table itself for the records.

Thanks again! Good luck all!

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working. It seemed to be the GROUP BY aspect, and some irregular data in my table itself for the records.  Some 0000-00-00 dates; is what I suspect.  Thank you for your comment, and suggestion to look into.

```
$lpcntWbqa = "SELECT portfolio_ledger.*,SUM(portfolio_ledger.plAmount) AS sum, portfolio_info.*,properties.*,property_portfolio.* FROM portfolio_ledger LEFT JOIN portfolio_info ON portfolio_ledger.psID = portfolio_info.ID LEFT JOIN property_portfolio ON portfolio_info.ppID = property_portfolio.ppID LEFT JOIN properties ON property_portfolio.pID = properties.pID WHERE properties.pOwner = '".$oRow['oID']."' AND portfolio_ledger.plNotify >= DATE_FORMAT( CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y/%m/01' ) AND portfolio_ledger.plNotify < DATE_FORMAT( CURRENT_DATE, '%Y/%m/01' ) AND (portfolio_ledger.plName = 'ST-Booking Fee' OR portfolio_ledger.plName = 'LT-Booking Fee')";
```

And returning the value as before; everything calculates and SUMS beautifully.

while ($lpTypeRow = mysql_fetch_array($lpcntXbqa))
{

```
$lastMonthsBookingValue = number_format($lpTypeRow['sum'], 2, '.', '');
```

}

Thanks again! Good luck all!